# How can I print all values that are true according to the statement provided

Tags: python, list

so I programmed my code in a way that whenever an input number is given, the output will always only display '1' or '4' after squaring each digit of the number AND adding the values of the squared digits together. Here is my code,

```
number = int()
sum_of_digits = 0
x = ''
while x not in ['1', '4']:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    x = str(sum_of_digits)
    number = sum_of_digits
    sum_of_digits = 0
print(x)
def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
```

So basically once you run my code, you will get either 1 or 4 and True or False, 1 being true and 4 being false, now what I want to do is to define a variable that will print out ALL NUMBERS (yes infinitely many numbers) that satisfy the condition 'True', how can I do that??

Comment: Put the code in a loop that tests all numbers in a range.

Comment: Put all this code in a function so you can call it on different numbers.

Comment: Yea I'm struggling to do that, can you please show me how to put in a loop

Comment: Already at least the third question today about happy numbers. Where is this coming from?

Comment: You want to print *all* of them? There are infinitely many.

Comment: yes I want to print all of them, I will then put all the infinitely many numbers in a list and then use smth like list[1] to get specific numbers

Comment: so yea can u please show me how to get ALL OF THEM?

Comment: I honestly can't tell whether you're serious or joking now :-)

Comment: @Broski If you are not just trolling, you should know that unless you have an infinite size of RAM, you would have a problem doing a calculation for an infinite amount of numbers.

Comment: I don't think I worded my question properly. so like lets say I have a code to figure out all the values that fit the condition true, so what I want to do is make sure that if I say I want the second number that fits the condition true, the output would be correct, my final output wont be infinite, I only want to extract or get ONE number out of list, depending on its position like lets say the o is the name of the list so o[1} will give me like 7 and o[2] will give me 10... how can I get that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explanation of infinite loop for `0`:

If we start loop from `0` it appears a infinite loop state because it never match `x not in ['1', '4']` this condition. To overcome this we can ignore `0` or put a condition to check if number is `0` or not.

**Try this:**

```
def GetX(number):
    sum_of_digits = 0
    x = ''
    while x not in ['1', '4']:
        for digit in str(number):
           sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
        x = str(sum_of_digits)
        number = sum_of_digits
        sum_of_digits = 0
    return x


def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False


for x in range(1, 101):
    if IsHappy((GetX(x))):
        print(x)

# or store happy number in a list
res = [x for x in range(1, 101) if IsHappy((GetX(x)))]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
1
7
10
13
19
23
28
31
32
44
49
68
70
79
82
86
91
94
97
100
[1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 100]
```

Comment: what if I want to put all those numbers in a list, how can I do that??

Comment: ur output is just what I needed, thank u very much, but I wanna put all these numbers  from the output in a list, how can I do that, without typing each number into the list??

Comment: @Broski I just update my answer, you can check that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that calculates the sum of digits in a function. You can then call the function in a loop.

```
def get_sum_of_digits(number):
    x = ''
    while x not in ['1', '4']:
        sum_of_digits = sum(int(digit)**2 for digit in str(number))
        x = str(sum_of_digits)
    return x

def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'

for i in range(1, 100):
    if IsHappy(get_sum_of_digits(i)) == 'True':
        print(i)
```

Comment: I dont get an output though, like its just blank... is there something I have to change??

Comment: Maybe none of the numbers from 0 to 100 are happy.

Comment: There are happy numbers between 0 and 100. Please check my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the `if IsHappy` line. Try it now.

Comment: It will not work though. please check my answer, i add an explanation for infinite loop there.

Comment: Doesn't work, you're confusing `x` and `numbers` and created an infinite loop.