# Why isnt my code printing anything after the command is given?

Tags: python, loops, numbers

So I've been tasked to find the result of all the numbers in range 1, 100 that fits the requirements according to my code, but there is an issue with it. So here is my code...

```
number = 7
sum_of_digits = 0
x = ''
while x not in ['1', '4']:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    x = str(sum_of_digits)
    number = sum_of_digits
    sum_of_digits = 0
print(x)
def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
print(IsHappy(x))
```

When I run this, this is the output I get,

```
1
True
```

but when I try to find ALL THE VALUES in range (1,100) THAT WILL RETURN TRUE, by using this code..

```
number = 7
sum_of_digits = 0
x = ''
while x not in ['1', '4']:
    for digit in str(number):
       sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
    x = str(sum_of_digits)
    number = sum_of_digits
    sum_of_digits = 0
print(x)
def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'
for x in range(0,100):
    if IsHappy(x) == '1':
        print(x)
```

I only get the output 1, but I'm supposed to be getting 1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97 because all these numbers is also true according to the code requirements... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `IsHappy` returns `'True'` or `'False'`. Is either of those values ever going to be equal to `'1'`?

Comment: I'd start by ensuring that your types are correct. `range(0,100)` will return integers, but you're looking at strings (e.g. `'1'`). You're also returning strings from `isHappy()` when I think you want to be returning a boolean.

Comment: You're not calculating the sum of digits of `x` in your loop.

Comment: Are you working on the same exercise as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69535094/how-can-i-print-all-values-that-are-true-according-to-the-statement-provided/69535828#69535828

Comment: What exactly are the requirements? I checked the question referred to by @Barmar and I couldn't understand that either

Comment: yea I am lol, working on the same one, but can you show me what I did wrong, maybe in the code itself, I dont really understand the explaination.

Comment: so the requirements are that for every digit in a number, I must square the digits and add them up together repeatedly until the output is either 1 or 4, now what Im trying to find is all the numbers in range 1, 100 that will produce the output of 1

Answer (score 2):

##### Explanation of infinite loop for `0`:

If we start loop from `0` it appears a infinite loop state because it never match `x not in ['1', '4']` this condition. To overcome this we can ignore `0` or put a condition to check if number is `0` or not.

**Try this:**

```
def GetX(number):
    sum_of_digits = 0
    x = ''
    while x not in ['1', '4']:
        for digit in str(number):
           sum_of_digits += (int(digit)**2)
        x = str(sum_of_digits)
        number = sum_of_digits
        sum_of_digits = 0
    return x


def IsHappy(x):
    if x == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False


for x in range(1, 101):
    if IsHappy((GetX(x))):
        print(x)

# or store happy number in a list
res = [x for x in range(1, 101) if IsHappy((GetX(x)))]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
1
7
10
13
19
23
28
31
32
44
49
68
70
79
82
86
91
94
97
100
[1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 100]
```

Comment: Yoo, thank u very much for helping me, I have another question, how can u make python print out specific digits of a number using codes??

Comment: like for instance if my number is x = 134, how do I make python print out 4 if the input is x[2]?

Comment: If add this answer here then it will not relevant. please add a different question for this. it will be better. if you like this answer then please give an upvote and mark this as an accepted answer. :) @Nutnicha

Comment: Why would it be plagarism if your class mates use this code but not if you use it? Deleting the helpful part is not how answers work on StacfkOverflow. If you are worried that using StackOverflow results in problems with your homework then do not ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: for me its fine because I put this guy's name in my list of collaborators before turning it in, and my professor has the link to this page and only allows different people to have different links, but if one of my mates use the exact same thing, then its gonna seem like me and the classmate copied each other.